# HTTP Basic Authentication Doesn't Seem to Work with urllib2 in python

Tags: python, urllib2, basic-authentication

I'm trying to download a page protected with basic authentication using urllib2. I'm using python 2.7 but I also tried it on another computer with python 2.5 and encountered the exact same behavior. I followed the example given in [this guide](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/authentication.shtml) as closely as I could and here is the code that I produced:

```
import urllib2

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, "http://authenticationsite.com/', "protected", "password")
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)

f = opener.open("http://authenticationsite.com/content.html")
print f.read()
f.close()
```

Unfortunately the server isn't mine so I can't share the details; I swapped them out above and below. When I run it I get the following Traceback:

```
  File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line
397, in open
response = meth(req, response)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
line 510, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line
435, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py",
line 369, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line
518, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code,
msg, hdrs, fp) urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP
Error 401: Authorization Required
```

Now, the interesting part is when I monitor the tcp traffic on the computer using ngrep:

```
ngrep host 74.125.224.49 interface:
wlan0 (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: (ip) and ( host 74.125.224.49
)
#### T 192.168.1.74:34366 -74.125.224.49:80 [AP]   GET /content.html
HTTP/1.1..Accept-Encoding:
identity..Host:
authenticationsite.com..Connection:
close..User-Agent:
Python-urllib/2.7.... 

## T 74.125.224.49:80 -192.168.1.74:34366 [AP]   HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required..Date: Sun, 27
Feb 2011 03:39:31 GMT..Server:
Apache/2.2.3 (Red
Hat)..WWW-Authenticate: Digest
realm="protected",
nonce="6NSgTzudBAA=ac585d1f7ae0632c4b90324aff5e39e0f1fc25
05", algorithm=MD5,
qop="auth"..Content-Length:
486..Connection: close..Content-Type: text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1....<!DOCTYPE HTML
PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML
2.0//EN">.<html><head>.<title>401 Authorization   
Required</title>.</head><body>.<h1>Authorization
Required</h1>.<p>This server could not
verify that you.are authorized to
access the document.requested.  Either
you supplied the wrong.credentials
(e.g., badpassword), or
your.browser doesn't understand how to
supply.the credentials
required.</p>.<hr>.<address>Apache/2.2.3
(Red Hat) Server at
authenticationsite.com Port
80</address>.</body></html>.  

####
```

It appears as though urllib2 is throwing that exception without even attempting to supply the credentials after getting the initial 401 error.

For comparion, here is the output of ngrep when I do the authentication in a web browser instead:

```
ngrep host 74.125.224.49 interface:
wlan0 (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: (ip) and ( host 74.125.224.49
)
#### T 192.168.1.74:36102 -74.125.224.49:80 [AP]   GET /content.html HTTP/1.1..Host:
authenticationsite.com..User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686;
en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027
Firefox/3.6.12..Accept: text  
/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8..Accept-Language:
en-us,en;q=0.5..Accept-Encoding:
gzip,deflate..Accept-Charset:
ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7..Keep-Alive:
115..Connection: keep-   alive....  
## T 74.125.224.49:80 -192.168.1.74:36102 [AP]   HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required..Date: Sun, 27
Feb 2011 03:43:42 GMT..Server:
Apache/2.2.3 (Red
Hat)..WWW-Authenticate: Digest
realm="protected",
nonce="rKCfXjudBAA=0c1111321169e30f689520321dbcce37a1876b
be", algorithm=MD5,
qop="auth"..Content-Length:
486..Connection: close..Content-Type: text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1....<!DOCTYPE HTML
PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML
2.0//EN">.<html><head>.<title>401 Authorization   
Required</title>.</head><body>.<h1>Authorization
Required</h1>.<p>This server could not
verify that you.are authorized to
access the document.requested.  Either
you supplied the wrong.credentials
(e.g., badpassword), or
your.browser doesn't understand how to
supply.the credentials
required.</p>.<hr>.<address>Apache/2.2.3
(Red Hat) Server at
authenticationsite.com Port
80</address>.</body></html>.  

######### T 192.168.1.74:36103 -74.125.224.49:80 [AP]   GET /content.html HTTP/1.1..Host:
authenticationsite.com..User-Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686;
en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101027
Firefox/3.6.12..Accept: text  
/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8..Accept-Language:
en-us,en;q=0.5..Accept-Encoding:
gzip,deflate..Accept-Charset:
ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7..Keep-Alive:
115..Connection: keep-   alive..Authorization: Digest
username="protected",
realm="protected",
nonce="rKCfXjudBAA=0c1111199162342689520550dbcce37a1876bbe",
uri="/content.html", algorithm=   MD5,
response="3b65dadaa00e1d6a1892ffff49f9f325",
qop=auth, nc=00000001,
cnonce="7636125b7fde3d1b".... 

##
```

And then followed with the content of the site.

I've been playing around with this for a while and am not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I would be very thankful if somebody can help me out!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that's caused by this:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest
```

It appears the resource is authenticated with Digest rather than Basic. Which means you should use [urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler) instead.

The code might be

```
import urllib2

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, "http://authenticationsite.com/", "protected", "password")

# use HTTPDigestAuthHandler instead here
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPDigestAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)

res = opener.open("http://authenticationsite.com/content.html")
print res.read()
res.close()
```

Comment: I have a issue in scrapping the URL of a site from my python script, which will extract all the sites containing the pdfs. I am working behind a proxy that asks for a user name and pwd when I open the browser for the first time. I am able to view the site and download pdfs from the site using the browser. However, I am not able to do it via code in Python.

The error I am facing is : "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required"

I am getting the error :"AbstractDigestAuthHandler does not support the following scheme: 'Negotiate'" Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use python NTLM module for this :

from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

import urllib2

user = "Your_username"

password = "your_Passwrd"

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()

passman.add_password(None, "http://your_Home_location/", user, password)

auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)

urllib2.install_opener(opener)

url = "http://Your_home_location/sub_locations"

response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

headers = response.info()

print("headers: {}".format(headers))

body = response.read()

print("response: " + body)

Answer (score -1):

```
import urllib2
# Create an OpenerDirector with support for Basic HTTP Authentication...
auth_handler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
auth_handler.add_password(realm='PDQ Application',
                          uri='https://mahler:8092/site-updates.py',
                          user='klem',
                          passwd='kadidd!ehopper')
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_handler)
# ...and install it globally so it can be used with urlopen.
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/login.html')
```

-- http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#examples

Comment: This is essentially what I was already doing. As Victor Lin pointed out in the other answer the problem was that the server actually uses Digest Authentication instead of Basic Authentication.